# Information about Blazor.platform functions

Tags: javascript, interop, blazor

In order to speed up javascript interop calls from a Blazor WASM web app I need to know a little bit more about what conversions are available. So far I have found one example [here](https://www.meziantou.net/generating-and-downloading-a-file-in-a-blazor-webassembly-application.htm) of the `Blazor.platform.toUint8Array`function that appears to convert an unmarshalled array (pointer(?)) and convert it to an Uint8 array. Is there a place where one can find what functions are available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you may find something [here...](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/e7d5306202a51949ec9e5c3f020c13fd4837099e/src/Components/Web.JS/src/Platform/Mono/MonoPlatform.ts)